# Template routes

Tags: ee2, ee

I can't understand how to made URL structure for page For eg

http://site.com/template_group/temlate1/template2/template3

http://site.com/services/cleaning/reviews/best

In admin panel, at template group services we have 4 templates

index cleaning reviews best

Every template have url

http://site.com/services/index/

http://site.com/services/cleaning/

http://site.com/services/reviews/

http://site.com/services/best/

I need to display some templates like this

http://site.com/services/cleaning/reviews/

or

http://site.com/services/cleaning/reviews/best/

What i need to type into template routes for template?

Comment: Please only post your questions one time on the site.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy enough to complete using something similar to

```
{if segment_1=="services"}
  {if segment_2=="cleaning"}
    {if segment_3=="reviews"}
      {if segment_4=="best"}
Content of the best review
      {if:elseif segment_4==""}
Content of all reviews
      {/if}
    {if:elseif segment_3==""}
Content of cleaning page
    {/if}
  {if:elseif segment_2==""}
Content of Services Page
  {/if}
{if:elseif segment_1==""}
Content of home page
{/if}
```

Then it's just a case of properly formatting your navigation